# Intel Realsense D435 Camera Not Detected

Tags: 16.04, usb, camera, ros

I am trying to use the [Intel® RealSense™ Depth Camera D435](https://www.intelrealsense.com/depth-camera-d435/) for navigation with ROS. My problem is that it is not detected at all by the computer (running Ubuntu 16.04), as when I run

```
rs-enumerate-devices
```

it says

> No device found. Is it plugged in?

I followed the install instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/realsense2_camera). There are no errors in the install and I have gone through the install twice to make sure I got everything. The computer is an Intel NUC and the camera is plugged in to a USB 3.0 port.

We plugged in the camera to a Windows 10 laptop, and we could view the video feed fine with the camera app. We are using the cable that came with the camera, and have tried plugging it into numerous different ports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the kernel needs to be patched but there's no patch script for groovy.  You need to use 20.04 LTS.